# Cakephp code equvivalent HTML code is different

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

My problem is that the Cakephp code for multiple checkbox and browser generates its equivalent code with **hidden** field with `0` value, which is unnecessary. Why is this hidden field generated by the browser? Any guidance would be welcome.

**CakePHP Code**

```
<div class="controls">
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'cricket')); ?> Cricket <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'football')); ?> FootBall <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'vollyball')); ?> VollyBall <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'chess')); ?> Chess
</div>
```

**Browser Generated Code**

```
<input name="interest[]" id="CheckBoxInterest_" value="0" type="hidden"><div id="uniform-CheckBoxInterest" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="interest[]" value="cricket" id="CheckBoxInterest" type="checkbox"></span></div> Cricket <br>
<input name="interest[]" id="CheckBoxInterest_" value="0" type="hidden"><div id="uniform-CheckBoxInterest" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="interest[]" value="football" id="CheckBoxInterest" type="checkbox"></span></div> FootBall <br>
<input name="interest[]" id="CheckBoxInterest_" value="0" type="hidden"><div id="uniform-CheckBoxInterest" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="interest[]" value="vollyball" id="CheckBoxInterest" type="checkbox"></span></div> VollyBall <br>
<input name="interest[]" id="CheckBoxInterest_" value="0" type="hidden"><div id="uniform-CheckBoxInterest" class="checker"><span><input style="opacity: 0;" name="interest[]" value="chess" id="CheckBoxInterest" type="checkbox"></span></div> Chess
```

Comment: You browser does not generate any code. This all comes from PHP. I suggest you read the documentation around the `Form->checkbox` helper

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your suggession I got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution!!! I added `hiddenField=>false` so It do not generate any **hidden** field. There is no browser issue but it cakephp functionality.

**CakePHP Code**.

```
<div class="controls">
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'cricket','hiddenField'=>false)); ?> Cricket <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'football','hiddenField'=>false)); ?> FootBall <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'vollyball','hiddenField'=>false)); ?> VollyBall <br>
    <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('interest', array('name'=>'interest[]','value'=>'chess','hiddenField'=>false)); ?> Chess
</div>
```

Comment: The hidden fields are actually *useful*. They help to send good default values in case nothing is being selected!

Answer (score 1):

Below code also generate multiple checkboxes :-

```
$interests = array(
               'cricket'=>'cricket',
               'football'=>'football',
               'vollyball'=>'vollyball',
               'chess'=>'chess'
             );
echo $this->Form->select('interest', $interests, array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

NOTE : However you may need to manage `div` which is generated with this code.